# Insert page number in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm building a Crystal report. I want to insert a page number for each page.
So, I have insert page number then in every page of my report, I can see

```
1
2
3
4
```

but now I want to insert this numeration:

```
1 of 4
2 of 4
3 of 4
4 of 4
```

How ca I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the field-explorer there are special-fields.
Take the pre-defined field called "Page N of M".

Alternatively you can create a formula with the following content:

```
ToText(PageNumber,0) & " of " & ToText(TotalPageCount,0)
```

(The `0` in the `ToText`-function removes the decimals from the page number.)

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Reports provide inbuilt field to add page numbers.

**Crystal Reports XI and Later:**

```
  Go to View -> Field Explorer

  Expand on Special Fields

  Locate the Page Number or Page N of M field and drag the field into the report
```

**Crystal Reports 8.5:**

```
   Go to Insert -> Field Object

   Expand on Special Fields

   Locate the Page Number or Page N of M field and drag the field into the report
```